# Mobile web design: ebay mobile

Tags: mobile, ebay

when I looked at the eBay mobile web site, I realized, they have two versions:

mobileweb.ebay.com > this seems to be the newer one
m.ebay.com > looks older

Is there a reason for it? Is the web site at m.ebay.com maybe more compatible with older devices?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like mobileweb.ebay.com is the newer mobile site and is designed to better fit the varying screen resolutions and viewport sizes that phones and tablets offer. m.ebay.com looks like it was designed to fit cell phones only. When viewing mobileweb.ebay.com I get a message saying it is in beta for my browser so I'm guessing mobileweb.ebay.com is going to replace m.ebay.com once they are sure it works properly across mobile devices.